# filter empty rows from a dataframe with R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with this structure :

```
Note.Reco  Reason.Reco  Suggestion.Reco  Contact
9          absent       tomorrow          yes
8                       tomorrow          yes
8          present      today             no
5                       yesterday         no
```

I would like to delete from this dataframe all the rows which have an empty value.

The expected result :

```
 Note.Reco  Reason.Reco  Suggestion.Reco  Contact
  9          absent       tomorrow          yes
  8          present      today             no
```

I try with this r instruction :

```
IRC_DF[!(is.na(IRC_DF$Reason.Reco) | IRC_DF$Reason.Reco==" "), ]
```

But I get the same input dataframe

Any idea please?

thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We need to change the syntax to

```
IRC_DF[!(!is.na(IRC_DF$Reason.Reco) & IRC_DF$Reason.Reco==""), ]
#   Note.Reco Reason.Reco Suggestion.Reco Contact
#1         9      absent        tomorrow     yes
#3         8     present           today      no
```

---

If multiple columns have NA or blanks (`""`), then

```
IRC_DF[Reduce(`&`, lapply(IRC_DF, function(x) !(is.na(x)|x==""))),]
```

#### data

```
IRC_DF <- structure(list(Note.Reco = c(9L, 8L, 8L, 5L), Reason.Reco = c("absent", 
 "", "present", ""), Suggestion.Reco = c("tomorrow", "tomorrow", 
 "today", "yesterday"), Contact = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no")), .Names = c("Note.Reco", 
 "Reason.Reco", "Suggestion.Reco", "Contact"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, when I do` "IRC_DF[!(!is.na(IRC_DF$Reason.Reco) & IRC_DF$Reason.Reco==""), ]" `  I get this  Warning message:
`In is.na(IRC_DF$Reason.Reco) :   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'`

Comment: @Datackatlon  I updated the data I used.  It is not giving the warning you showed

Comment: thank you, but there is case where "Note.Reco" and " Reason.Reco"  are only empty

Comment: @Datackatlon  In that case, subset only those columns, and apply the code

Comment: But I need these column for other rows because they are not empty in some case....

Comment: @Datackatlon  Please update in your post.  I am not sure whehter I understand your comment.  My post was based on your example

Answer (score 8):

Or use dplyr's `filter` function.

```
filter(IRC_DF, !is.na(Reason.Reco) | Reason.Reco != "")
```

Comment: filter(IRC_DF, Reason.Reco != "{}") this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same error when fitting training data to a single decision tree. But it got resolved once I remove the NA values from the raw data before splitting in training and test set. I guess it was a mismatch of data when we split and f
fitting in model.
some steps:
1: remove NA from other then predictor col.
2: Now split in training and test set.
3: Train model now and hope it fix error now.

Comment: Kindly elaborate the question with examples and code snippets.